# Conditional predicted probabilities using glm

Tags: r

Simple question I can't figure out.  I am trying to generate conditional predicted probabilities from a model including an interaction.  For example, I wanted to be able to compare the predicted probability of when x2==1 and x3==0 with the predicted probability of when x2==0 and x3==1.

I am trying to do this as follows:

```
model <- glm(y~x1 + x2 * x3, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=data)
predprob1 <- predict(model, type="response", newdata=(x1=mean(x1) & x2==1 & x3==0))
predprob2 <- predict(model, type="response", newdata=(x1=mean(x1) & x2==0 & x3==1))
probdiff<-predprob1-predprob2
```

After that, I need to calculate the 95CI for probdiff. I am sure this is simple for you R geniuses out there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As posed, the question admits of no possible solution since glm with the default Gaussian distribution does not produce estimates of probability. It is also likely that you are getting the estimates for the original data  (or an error) as a result since you have not include all the predictor values in your 'newdata' argument (and you have named it incorrectly.)

Comment: Hi there, I am adding in corrections that I think should help? I tried to set X1 to the mean value, although maybe that code is wrong too.

Comment: You are still not offering `newdata` a dataframe object, and even if you were offering the correct class, you are not assigning the results of mean(x1) the name (namely 'x1') that it needs to have.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (untested in absence of working example):

```
model <- glm(y~x1 + x2 * x3, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=data)
predprob1 <- predict(model, type="response", 
                     newdata=with(data, data.frame(x1=mean(x1) & x2=1 & x3=0))
predprob2 <- predict(model, type="response", 
                     newdata=with(data, data.frame(x1=mean(x1) & x2=0 & x3=1))
probdiff <- predprob1-predprob2
```

The other R-error was to use '==' for assignment. It is for logical tests.